# Breeze Query: Network shows data is returned but javascript results contains an empty model

Tags: breeze

I am trying to retrieve data from the server using breeze js.  When the code in the controller snippet below runs, it hits the server and returns the correct data to the client (verified in Chrome Network tools).  However, if you analyze the data.results in the promise handler, the model in the results appears like a new version of the entity with all default values for the fields (zeroes, null, etc.).  No errors appear in the console.

This only happens if you go directly to this page.  If you go to the homepage of the site then navigate to this page everything works correctly.  It appears to be some sort of race condition when loading the site but I'm not exactly sure where to look.

Any ideas?

```
    //From tnDataContext
    function getFromAllTasks(criteria, orderBy, take, skip) {
        var predicates = getPredicatesFromTaskCriteria(criteria);

        if (!orderBy)
            orderBy = 'taskStatus.taskInboxSortOrder, taskPriority.priorityLevel, endDueDate DESC';

        var predicate = breeze.Predicate.and(predicates);
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Tasks')
                    .where(predicate)
                    .expand('parentTask, taskNotes')
                    .orderBy(orderBy)
                    .inlineCount()
                    .take(take)
                    .skip(skip);

        $rootScope.appProcesses++;
        return em.executeQuery(query).finally(function () {
            $rootScope.appProcesses--;
        });
    }

    //From Angular Page Controller
    return tnDataContext.getFromAllTasks(criteria, sortOrder, take, skip)
            .then(function (data) {
                if (data.results.length > 0) {
                    tasks = data.results;
                    $scope.task = tnDataContext.getEntity('Task', id);
                    $scope.childTasks = tasks.filter(function (t) {
                        return t.taskId != id;
                    });

                    determineCanUseActions($scope.task.taskType.taskTypeEntityTypes[0]);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Make sure Breeze has the metadata loaded before performing the query.  That's the typical race condition.

Comment: From what I can tell the metadata has been loaded at the time of the query.

Comment: Maybe the JsonResultsAdapter hasn't been configured yet, so Breeze doesn't know how to interpret the results?